# importing excel into matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 4 folders in the same directory where each folder contains ~19 .xls files. I have written the code below to obtain the name of each of the folders and the name of each .xls file within the folders.

```
path='E:\Practice'; 
folder = path; 
dirListing = dir(folder); 
dirListing=dirListing(3:end);%first 2 are just pointers
for i=1:length(dirListing);
    f{i} = fullfile(path, dirListing(i,1).name);%obtain the name of each folder
    files{i}=dir(fullfile(f{i},'*.xls'));%find the .xls files
    for j=1:length(files{1,i});
        File_Name{1,i}{j,1}=files{1,i}(j,1).name;%find the name of each .xls file
    end
end
```

Now I'm trying to import the data from excel into matlab by using xlsread. What I'm struggling with is knowing how to load the data into matlab within a loop where the excel files are in different directories (different folders).

This leaves me with a 1x4 cell named File_Name where each cell refers to a different folder located under 'path', and within each cell is then the name of the spreadsheets wanting to be imported. The size of the cells vary as the number of spreadsheets in each folder varies.

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to do different things based on which directory the xls file is in? Or when you are loading the data can you treat every XLS file the same?

Comment: Well the number of spreadsheets in each file is different i.e. 19, 19, 19, 18. But apart from that they are treated the same. So far I have written: for i=1:length(File_Name); a(i)=length(File_Name{1,i}); for j=1:a(i) [num{j},txt{j},raw{j}]=xlsread(File_Name{1,i}{j,1}); end end                                                        But the main problem at the minute is telling matlab that the data is stored in different directories

Comment: Is this your question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329236/matlab-several-excel-files/8329966 If so, what you have to do is to add the subfolders determination, what you have in this question. Let me know if you don't understand something in my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your problem, but all you have to do is concatenate the strings that contain directory (f{}) and the file name.  Modifying your code:

```
for i=1:length(dirListing);
    f{i} = fullfile(path, dirListing(i,1).name);%obtain the name of each folder
    files{i}=dir(fullfile(f{i},'*.xls'));%find the .xls files
    for j=1:length(files{1,i});
        File_Name{1,i}{j,1}=files{1,i}(j,1).name;%find the name of each .xls file
        fullpath = [f{i} '/' File_Name{1,i}{j,1}];
        disp(['Reading file: ' fullpath])
        x = xlsread(fullpath);
    end
end
```

This works on *nix systems.  You may have to join the filenames with a '\' on Windows.  I'll find a more elegant way and update this posting.

**Edit**: The command `filesep` gives the forward or backward slash, depending on your system.  The following should give you the full path:

```
fullpath = [f{i} filesep File_Name{1,i}{j,1}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this helper function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550), written by a member of the matlab community.
It allows you to recursively search through directories to find files that match a certain pattern.  This is a super handy function to use when looking to match files.

You should be able to find all your files in a single call to this function. Then you can loop through the results of the rdir function, loading the files one at a time into whatever data structure you want.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654459/201800) by gnovice is an excellent way to do exactly this. Just use `regexpi` to filter for .xls after gathering all the files.